# Emacs Dired - C-x C-f to create a new file gives me suggestions of existing files

Tags: emacs, dired

I'm trying to create a file in dired mode in emacs. I am in the right directory and when I press C-x C-f as suggested elsewhere on SO and type 'img' (that's the name of the file I want to create), it tries to find existing files from other directories including the pattern 'img'. Then I'm stuck as if I press enter, it'll open the first suggested file containing the pattern 'img' from other directories, TAB will just go over the suggestions.

Please advise.

Comment: Tell us what function is being called when you press `C-x C-f`? You can learn this by pressing `C-h k` then `C-x C-f`

Comment: It looks like it runs ido-find-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably using `ido-find-file` with which you can interactively select a file by typing a substring of that file name.

If you want to temporarily disable this feature (i.e. for your current search only) just press `C-f` before typing the name of your new file (i.e. immediatly after `C-x C-f`).